# Unable to implement API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

(Note: I am a beginner!)
I am doing an ASP.NET Core Website and have to show the list of all countries with their travel advisory scores in a table.
I can't display the data using a Travel Advisory API. Each country is a separate key and are different classes when I paste the JSON as classes.

How can I call each country's class (eg. `AU`) and display the data under the country using a loop? The problem is that there are too many countries so I hope to use a loop for this. As you can see in the code below, I can only show one country at a time as each country is a different class.

- Basic API endpoint: `https://www.travel-advisory.info/api`
- Optional parameter: `https://www.travel-advisory.info/api?countrycode=AU` (*restricts the result list to a single country*)

My `TravelAdvisory` controller's action method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    string countryCode = "AU"; //I plan to have multiple country codes in a loop, 
//just haven't done so yet as I have issues showing the data for all country codes

    // Make Web API call to get a list of travel advisories
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.travel-advisory.info");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api"); 

    if (countryCode != null)
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync("/api?countrycode=" + countryCode);
    }

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Rootobject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);

        float score = model.data.AU.advisory.score; 
 //here, I can only get the score for one country since class names are different.

        List<float> dataList = new List<float>();
        dataList.Add(score);

        TempData["Score"] = Convert.ToString(score);

        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View(new List<Data>());
    }
}
```

`TravelAdvisory` model classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Api_Status api_status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Api_Status
{
    public Request request { get; set; }
    public Reply reply { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public string item { get; set; }
}

public class Reply
{
    public string cache { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public AD AD { get; set; }
    public AE AE { get; set; }
    public AF AF { get; set; }
    public AG AG { get; set; }
    public AI AI { get; set; }
    public AL AL { get; set; }
    public AM AM { get; set; }
    ...
```

My code:

- Model: https://controlc.com/da48a2be
- Controller: https://controlc.com/51d938c7

Comment: you can add a parameter to your index method as countrycode

Comment: @viveknuna yup I didn't add it in yet, as I just wanted to figure out how to print the scores for each country code with a loop first

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter to the Index method like this and write your logic accordingly.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string countryCode)
{
```

And you can use the code in `if` and `else`, you you want to get records for all countires if `countryCode` is `null` or emotry string.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryCode))
{
    response = await client.GetAsync("/api);
}
else
{
    response = await client.GetAsync("/api?countrycode=" + countryCode);
}
```

**Edit**:

You can use reflection to get all the properties and proceed further.

```
Data data = ...;
foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can I get the score for each countryCode? Since I can only retrieve the score by class (i.e.  model.data.AU.advisory.score) and each country Code is a separate class.

Comment: if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Rootobject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);

                float score = model.data.AU.advisory.score;
                List<float> dataList = new List<float>();
                dataList.Add(score);
                TempData["Score"] = Convert.ToString(score);

                return View();

            }

Comment: This is my code to retrieve the score, but the issue is that I only can get the score for one country at a time and I have no idea how to do this in a loop.

Comment: thank you! now I get an error saying that object does not match target type and since I'm a beginner, I have no idea how to continue from your answer and display the data hahaha, so sorry!

Comment: @Jan Dear, you need to put some efforts, Please make sure that StackOverFlow is not for a readymade solution. I have answered your main problem

Comment: yup rest assured I am trying my best but still can't do it! sorry about it and thanks for the help!